# How to properly declare json modules containing tuples in typescript?

Tags: json, typescript, module, tuples, tsc

I'm writing client-side only project which has lots of static data in form of json. To easily manage all the data I want to split it into multiple json files but also have some typing for those files to make life easier.

The project structure looks like this:

```
├─src
│  └─data
│    ├─jsonModel.ts
│    ├─part1data.json
│    ├─part1data.d.ts
│    └─index.ts
├─packaje.json
└─tsconfig.json
```

`jsonModel.ts`:

```js
export type Key = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d";
export type KeyOrNull = Key | null
export type Tuple = [KeyOrNull, KeyOrNull, string];
export type Part1Data = {
    prop: string,
    otherProp: number
    tuples: Tuple[]
};
```

`part1data.json`:

```json
{
  "prop": "abc",
  "otherProp": 123,
  "tuples": [
    ["a", "a", "abc1"],
    ["b", "b", "abc2"],
    ["b", null, "abc3"]
  ]
}
```

`part1data.d.ts`:

```js
declare module "./part1data.json" {
    import {Part1Data} from "./jsonModel";
    const object: Part1Data;
    export default object;
}
```

`index.ts`:

```js
import {Part1Data} from "./jsonModel";

import elements from "./part1data.json";

type Data = {
    part1Data: Part1Data
}

const data: Data = {
    part1Data: elements
}

export default data;
```

And `tsconfig.json` just in case:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

When I build the project I get the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ prop: string; otherProp: number; tuples: (string | null)[][]; }' is not assignable to type 'Part1Data'.
  Types of property 'tuples' are incompatible.                                                                         
    Type '(string | null)[][]' is not assignable to type 'Tuple[]'.                                                    
      Type '(string | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'Tuple'.                                                      
        Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.                                                        
     9 |                                                                                                               
    10 | const data: Data = {
  > 11 |     part1Data: elements
       |     ^^^^^^^^^
    12 | }
    13 |
    14 | export default data;
```

It looks like tsc does even see the typings, because it tells me that the object is of type `{ prop: string; otherProp: number; tuples: (string | null)[][]; }`. Obviously, it cannot be assigned to `Part1Data` because that's a complitely different type. I tried moving `part1data.d.ts` into the root project directory (next to `package.json`) but still it does not work.
How do I make tsc properly recognize typings?

Comment: Something odd seems to be happening in `part1data.d.ts`, why do you need this?

Comment: [Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to the rescue.

Comment: @beautifulcoder what's exactly wrong with it? I have a model defined in a separate file, I import that model and declare a module that returns an object with a specific type from my model

Comment: @lowercase93 You can accomplish the same by importing the specific type in `jsonModel.ts`. Type definitions are mostly for when you need to package the compiled codes as a separate library.